# Querying a tree structure for getting its children

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested-set-model

I have a tree (nested set) table composed by persons in an organization. Each person has a rank in the organization. I'm trying to form a query that will get me the down line (children) for a person (all persons under that person) except if they are under a person that has the same rank or higher rank than that person. (But I want to keep the person with the same or higher rank). I don't need the exact query I'm just trying to get a hint or idea on how to make it happen.

Comment: You can use a recursive CTE or sql-servers build in Hierarchicalid type https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx

Comment: Thanks, let me try that.